# magento custom payment method, send email while capturing

Tags: magento

I am creating a custom payment method and use "authorize_capture" as the payment_action.
If everything goes well, magento automatically creates invoice once the payment is successful.
My question is how to send email after the invoice is created?

I know i can do this using observer, buy it will make all payment methods to fire this observer if they make invoice as well.

is there another way?
for example by marking the payment as "send email" inside capture() method maybe?

Edited:
I just found this link
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8389/paypal-payment-pro-the-invoice-email-is-not-sent
It seems that Paypal Payment PRO does the same, it can't send invoice email when using "auth and capture".
So at the end, i used the observer way and only send email when the payment method is my extension.